# How to open a separate socket connection in Scotty or Yesod?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, yesod, scotty

I am building an application that has to connect to an IRC network (open a socket) and also host a web app. Some data should be shared between an IRC part and Http part. What's the best way to achieve that kind of concurrency in Haskell? Should `Control.Monad.STM` be used to implement this? Is this something the web framework should support as well or is it possible to fork before starting Scotty?

Comment: if you don't want to use some low-level stuff http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-conduit-2.4.0/docs/Data-Conduit-TMChan.html migth be interesting for you here

Comment: STM's TVar or TQueue can certainly be used to sync data between the threads.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following works surprisingly great. I ended up using STM.TQueue.

```
listen :: SSL.SSL -> IO ()
listen ssl = do
  lines <- BL.lines `fmap` SSL.lazyRead ssl
  mapM_ (processLine ssl . show) lines

processQueue :: SSL.SSL -> TQueue String -> IO ()
processQueue ssl queue = forever $ do newData <- atomically $ readTQueue queue
                                      privmsg ssl newData

web_service :: TQueue String -> IO ()
web_service queue = scotty 25000 $ do
  get "/" $ do
    liftIO $ atomically $ writeTQueue queue "test passed"    
    status ok200

irc_bot :: [AddrInfo] -> TQueue String -> IO ()
irc_bot addrs queue = do ssl <- connectToServer (head addrs)
                         forkIO $ listen ssl
                         processQueue ssl queue

main = withOpenSSL $ do
  let hints = defaultHints { addrSocketType = Stream, addrFamily = AF_INET }
  addrs <- getAddrInfo (Just hints) (Just "irc.freenode.com") (Just "6697")
  queue <- atomically newTQueue
  forkIO $ irc_bot addrs queue
  web_service queue
```